# material design angular input require

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, required, angular-ngmodel

Does Angular Material Design require an input ng-model to be equal to a variable in order for required to work?

Without using Material Design, the following error checking works perfectly fine.

```
<label>First Name (as it appears on your card)</label>
<input type="text" name="firstName" data-ng-model="test" required/>
```

Using Material Design though, the following always returns invalid unless the user types something, deletes it, and types something else.

```
<md-input-container>
  <label>First Name (as it appears on your card)</label>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" data-ng-model="test" required/>
</md-input-container>
```

However, I set test equal to something in the scope, then error checking works fine:

```
$scope.test = 'this value';
```

Is there a way to error check using Material Design without needing to specify a default value for fields?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean error checking not working, but the second sounds like the correct behavior. A field is marked as incorrect when the required attr is present if empty AND touched (ie edited) and not before. This way the required fields are not marked invalid as soon as the form is presented.

Comment: But with the second, without `$scope.test = 'this value';` in the controller, then as soon as I type text, eg: 'hello',  then I won't validate. I need to first type something, and then delete it, then type something again for it to be recognized as true. So it's marked as incorrect after being touched AND not empty.

Comment: could you post a jsfiddle/plunker demonstrating the above?

Comment: I see a slightly different behavior. The field is not marked in error until I select it for editing. Once selected, it is marked as error before I can type anything in it. Once I type, the error goes away. I would have expected the error to not appear until I select and then leave without adding anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might not have initialized the ng-model variable in the controller.

Try initializing the variable, 
`$scope.test = '';`